# How do I check whether or not I'm logged in or not?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I want to test whether or not this request worked or not. is there a way to check the html or do something like geturl() while using session on requests?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 2.7.11
#
import requests


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

cookie = {'enwiki_session': '17ab96bd8ffbe8ca58a78657a918558'}


url = 'https://127.0.0.1/login.php'


payload = {'user': 'admin','pass': 'admin123'}


Page = requests.Session()
Page.post(url,headers=headers,cookies=cookie,data=payload)

#print Page.content
#print Page.geturl()
```

Comment: look at the response content? Surely you know what a successful login looks like?

Comment: is there a way for me to check what link the script is currently on after the post request? something similar to geturl()

Comment: You mean  `p = Page.post(url,headers=headers,cookies=cookie,data=payload)` `print p.url`?